# how to send in parameter for app.callback function for plotly dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I would like to create mulitiple graphs that send in a different parameter to 'INPUT_PARAM' in the update_graph_scatter function. Where do I pass in the INPUT_PARAM?

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='graph-update',
            interval=1000 * 60,
            n_intervals = 0,
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
        [Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph_scatter(INPUT_PARAM):
```

Answer (score 1):

That is controlled by the `Input` values and `State` values you define in the `app.callback` decorator. In this case, it would be the `n_intervals` from `graph-update`.

Comment: I see, but I want to pass in a string to load a different type of graph. Will I need to create a new function then?

Comment: What string would you want to pass and and how would you want it to update the graph?

Comment: I'm using the string passed in to query a database and return a graph of the queried word

Comment: Where would that string be coming from? Is the user submitting it? Then you might want `dcc.Input` for that.